# How do I execute a command on a successful build on TFS2010?

Tags: tfs, msdeploy

I've got TFS2010 up and running and building a [`webdeploy`](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) deployment package.

Into my directory:

```
C:\TFS-BUILDS\Example Build\Example Build_20100414.44\_PublishedWebsites
```

I get the following two directories:

```
WebsiteName
WebsiteName_Package
```

All I want to do is run the following command on a successful build - to deploy the site:

```
WebsiteName_Package\WebsiteName.deploy /Y
```

How can I customize the build process template to actually run that package? Under TFS 2010 you have to use the process templates (no more TFSBuild.csproj stuff).

I've tried duplicating the `DefaultProcessTemplate.xaml` file, but it basically kills my Visual Studio when I open it.

How can I edit the .xaml by hand to run this simple command on a successful build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Towards the end of Chapter 21 of a book I co-authored, I talk about customizing the build process in 2010 and give the XAML snippets on what to add where. It might help you.  Take a look here

- [Professional Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2010](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Application-Lifecycle-Management-with-Visual-Studio-2010.productCd-0470484268.html)

Contains the build chapter - Chapter 21 (as a free download) and the sample code on the Wrox website.

Comment: this probably needs to have the parts of the PDF (thanks @Martine) actually placed into the answer of SO